# how to write exact encryption code in java and node?

Tags: java, node.js, encryption

I need to translate the following code in Java:

```
public static String encode(String chave, final String value)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    final Key keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(chave.getBytes(), "AES");

    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    System.out.println(Hex.encodeHex(new byte[16]));


    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));

    final byte[] message = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());

    return new String(Hex.encodeHex(message));
}
```

to Node. I am trying:

```
var encrypt = function (key, data) {
    var iv = new Buffer('');

    decodeKey = new Buffer(key, "utf-8");
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc', decodeKey, iv);

    cipher.setAutoPadding(true);
    //return cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'hex') + '   ' + cipher.final('hex');

    var encrypted = Buffer.concat([
        cipher.update(data, "binary"),
        cipher.final()
    ]);

    return encrypted.toString('hex');

};
```

But the result is not the same. It looks like there is an issue in the iv buffer but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why do you want to have the same output? It would be a good practice to use a random IV.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues. If you want to provide an IV, you need to call `crypto.createCipheriv` instead of `crypto.createCipher`. The latter takes a password instead of a key and derives the key and IV from that using OpenSSL's EVP_BytesToKey.

The other issue is that you should use an IV of correct length: `var iv = Buffer.alloc(16);`

Other issues could be the encodings that are all over the place:

- `value.getBytes()` uses the default character encoding and my be different from machine to machine. Always define a specific character encoding like: `value.getBytes("UTF-8")`
- `cipher.update(data, "binary")` assumes that `data` is Latin1 encoded which doesn't match with the Java code. Use `cipher.update(data, "utf-8")`.
- `decodeKey = new Buffer(key, "utf-8");` looks bad, because keys should be randomly chosen. A binary representation of a key doesn't usually result in a valid UTF-8 encoding. Remember that keys are not passwords.

---

#### Security considerations:

The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.